# Google Calendar API and C# - 403 Forbidden

Tags: c#, .net, google-calendar-api

Looking for some help. I've been through all the documentation, SO and Google and still having no luck.

I'm trying to integrate with the Google Calendar API in my Web Application for a "Check Availability" feature. Currently I'm at the very basics of hooking in, and the furthest I've got is just trying to authenticate and pull some data out. I've included my code below - all I'm getting are **403 Forbidden** errors after following all the advice I've seen.

Can anyone spot where I am going wrong?

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Register the authenticator. The Client ID and secret have to be copied from the API Access
  // tab on the Google APIs Console.
  var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description);
  provider.ClientIdentifier = "MY_CLIENT_ID";
  provider.ClientSecret = "MY_SECRET";

  var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, GetAuthentication);

  // Create the service.
  var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
  {
      Authenticator = auth
  });

  EventsResource.ListRequest req = service.Events.List("primary");

  if (req != null)
  {
      var events = req.Fetch();

      if (events != null)
      {
          litResult.Text = events.Items.Count().ToString();
      }
      else
      {
          litResult.Text = "Zilch.";
      }
  }
  else
  {
      litResult.Text = "Nada.";
  }
}

private static IAuthorizationState GetAuthentication(NativeApplicationClient arg)
{
  // Get the auth URL:
  IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[] { "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds" });
  state.Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl);
  Uri authUri = arg.RequestUserAuthorization(state);

  // Request authorization from the user (by opening a browser window):
  Process.Start(authUri.ToString());
  Console.Write("  Authorization Code: ");
  string authCode = Console.ReadLine();
  Console.WriteLine();

  // Retrieve the access token by using the authorization code:
  return arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCode, state);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think where you have:

```
provider.ClientIdentifier = "MY_CLIENT_ID";
provider.ClientSecret = "MY_SECRET";
```

You really need to fill it in with the client id and secret given on the [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) page...

Comment: Thanks for the words of wisdom...

I ended up reverting to Calendar API v2; had it working after 10 minutes.